# Where exactly does application.conf live in the project directory structure?

Tags: scala, playframework, lagom

The [Play website](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/AccessingAnSQLDatabase) says it should be in "conf", but the Lagom default HelloeWorld example places it under the "resources" directory within /applicationProject/src/main". "conf/" does not even show up anywhere in the directory structure in Lagom. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [default Play project layout](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Anatomy#The-Play-application-layout) 
`application.conf` located at `conf/application.conf`. So if you will inject `play.api.Configuration` this will represent parsed and loaded config from that file.

On another hand I suppose, Lagom is library, which relies on default [Maven project layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), which differs from default Play layout, in which `src/main/resources` is standard folder for resources like configuration, which is why in Lagom project example you see `application.conf` in another folder then in Play.

What you can do as an option: take `play.api.Configuration.underlying` and pass manually to Lagom code.

Or keep using standard Maven project layout for Play via special plugin introduced after version 2.6.8: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Highlights26#PlayService-sbt-plugin-(experimental)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think so. I am unable to test it at the moment, but will come back with questions when I get to it. For now, thanks and much appreciated!